# Javascript function behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a problem with javascript.
In my code there is a radio button, on click it should call the `UcSelect()` function. I tried the code below but it didn't work.
The function just try to print something in order to help me to understand the behavior of the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js">   

    function UcSelect() {
        alert('hello1');
        if ($("#rbtTipo :checked").val() == 'E') {
            alert("aaaaaaaaaaaaa");
        }
        if ($("#rbtTipo :checked").value == 'E') {
            alert("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb");
        }
        return true;
    }

</script>
```

And the radio button:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtTipo" runat="server" Style="margin-top: 4px; margin-bottom: 8px;" onclick="UcSelect();" >
        <asp:ListItem Value="E">&nbsp; Nuovo Coefficiente Energia</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="G">&nbsp; Nuovo Coefficiente Gas</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Answer (score 2):

[`script` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) can have a `src` attribute **or** content, but not both. If they have both, the content is ignored (the content is considered "script documentation," not code).

As you are using ASP.NET and `rbtTipo` is a  server control you need to use [`Control.ClientID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.110).aspx).

`<%= rbtTipo.ClientID %>` will Gets the control ID for HTML markup that is generated by ASP.NET.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    function UcSelect() {
        var value = $("#<%= rbtTipo.ClientID %> :checked").val();
        if (value == 'E') {
            alert("aaaaaaaaaaaaa");
        }
        if (value == 'G') {
            alert("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb");
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Probably needs to use `ClientID` somewhere as well. The `ID` on ASP.Net controls is the server-side ID.

Comment: Thanks it works, but the statement : $("#rbtTipo :checked") return []

Comment: @user3066925, try `$("#<%= rbtTipo.ClientID %> :checked").val()`

Comment: @Satpal, if i put the script in the same UC where the button is, is like the function is out of scope, for let the function fire i have to put it on another UC that include the UC where is the radio button, but in this uc i haven't the rbtTipo

Comment: @user3066925, What is UC? Is your primary problem which you asked is solved? Are you facing new problem?

Comment: UC is the user control, i'm working on an ascx that include another ascx.

Comment: My primary problem is half-solved, cause i can't scope the function in the same file where the button is

Comment: @Lancilnove, then make few changes to code  try with `onclick="UcSelect(this);"` and `$(":checked", this).val()`

Comment: @Satpal, sadly is not working. I see this on debugger: Uncaught ReferenceError: UcSelect is not definedonclick @ CoefficientiPage.aspx:1

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your code. You have to close the script tag properly

Add there is a redundant code of checking value E. You should remove that code or update it to check for G. For your reference, I have updated the code below.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

    function UcSelect() {
        alert('hello1');
        if ($("#rbtTipo :checked").val() == 'E') {
            alert("aaaaaaaaaaaaa");
        }
        if ($("#rbtTipo :checked").val() == 'G') {
            alert("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb");
        }
        return true;
    }

</script>
```